# in redux framework custom css is not working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I am using Redux Framework for theme options in my Wordpress theme. All is working fine expect one thing. When I write CSS code like:

[image: Source Code]

It does not take up CSS because we using > sign in CSS.

When I saw the source code then it becomes like this

[image: Output]

What can I do about this?

Comment: Try adding a space between the `a` and the `{`. It might be easier to add a class to those `a` elements and style that single class rather than all the descendant selectors.

Comment: thanks and tried but Still no luck

Comment: Can you send me a login? I can check it out for you. Send to shawn@fencepencil.com

Comment: thanks but I can't provide the login details